# How do I use the same method when chaining over an object?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

```
var string = function (base) { 
  return { 
    add: function (added) {
      return base + added;
  }
 }
}

text = string("robots").add(" are awesome");

console.log(text);

// robots are awesome

text2 = string("robots").add(" are awesome").add(" everytime!");

console.log(text2);

// TypeError: Object robots are awesome has no method 'add'
```

How do I make this work? What can you do to share the method 'add' across certain objects within the scope of the function?

Comment: You use the same method in a chain by using a concept called Cascades.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be [achieved](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/k22fu/2/) with Functional inheritance and cascading.  Which is what the OP appears to be going for. No pseudoclassical inheritance.

```
var string = function (someStartString) {
    var that = {
        append: function (newString) {
              that.currentString += newString;
              return that;//enable cascades        
        }
        ,currentString: someStartString
     };
     return that;
}
```

Example calls

```
var textObj = string("robots").append(" are awesome");

console.log(textObj.currentString);//output: robots are awesome

// robots are awesome

var text2Obj = string("robots").append(" are awesome").append(" everytime!");

console.log(text2Obj.currentString);//output: robots are awesome everytime!
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only return `string(base + added)`. It won't work properly. It'll return an Object when you `console.log`.

```
var string = function (base) { 
  return { 
    add: function (added) {
      return string(base + added);
  }
 }
}
console.log(string("test ").add("this ").add("thing"));
// outputs [object Object]
```

Above example fails for what you want. You may try this:

```
var string = function (base) { 
  return { 
    add: function (added) {
      base += added;
      return string(this.toString());
    },
   toString: function() {
      return base;
    }
 }
}

console.log(string("test ").add("this ").add("thing").toString());
// outputs "test this thing"
```

This will output correctly.

You also could extend String.prototype and add the `add` method.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of extending String as a fix but I hear it's bad to proto over core Objects? Would it be okay to do it anyways in my situation?

Comment: There are two lines of thinking. One says it's bad, one say it's ok. I think you have to look for pros and cons of each one and choose by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You want to return a `string` from your `add` function:

```
var string = function (base) { 
  return { 
    add: function (added) {
      return string(base + added);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var string = function (base) { 
  return { 
    add: function (added) {
      return string(base + added);
    },
    toString: function() {
      return base;
    }
 }
}
```

Edit: you may also want to add a `toString` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a plain string, not an instance of your constructor. On plain strings, `.add` is not available.

You can solve this by returning a new instance, so that the `.add` function is available on the result:

```
return string( base + added );
```

Then it basically goes like this:

```
string("robots").add(" are awesome").add("everytime!");
string("robots are awesome").add("everytime!");
string("robots are awesomeeverytime!");
```

instead of:

```
string("robots").add(" are awesome").add("everytime!");
"robots are awesome".add("everytime!");
<error>
```